# Function isn't called properly?

Tags: python, function

I have the code for caesar cipher encryption and I am trying to call the `cleanup()` function inside the `fancy_caesar()` function in order for the input keyword and message to be 'cleaned up.':

```
#with just .upper()
my_string = ''

def string():
    my_string = input("Enter your string: ")
    res = cleanup()
    print(res)

def cleanup(self):
    res = ''
    _char = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    lower_char = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    all_char = _char + lower_char
    for ch in my_string:
        if ch in all_char:
            res += ch
    return (res.upper())


def swap(x, i, j):
    i, j = sorted((i, j))
    if i and j in range(len(x)):
        return x[:i] + x[j] + x[i+1:j] + x[i] + x[j+1:]
    else:
        return None   
def inputs():
    x = input('Enter your string: ')
    i = int(input('Enter the index of the first letter: '))
    j = int(input('Enter the 2nd index of the next letter: '))
    print(swap(x, i, j))


#print(swap(x, i, j))



def fancy_caesar(message, keyword, true_false_statement):
    count = 0
    while count == 0:
        true_false_statement = str(input("Type True if you want to encrypt.\nType false if you want to decrypt: "))
        if true_false_statement == 'true' or true_false_statement == 'True' or true_false_statement == 't' or true_false_statement == 'T':
            count = count +1
        elif true_false_statement == 'false' or true_false_statement == 'False' or true_false_statement == 'F' or true_false_statement == 'f':
            count = count + 1
        else:
            print('None')
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    translated_message = ""
    keyword_index = 0

    for character in message:
        if character in alphabet:
            number = alphabet.find(character)
            if true_false_statement == 'true' or true_false_statement == 'True' or true_false_statement == 't' or true_false_statement == 'T':
                number = number + (ord(keyword[keyword_index]) - ord('a'))
            elif true_false_statement == 'false' or true_false_statement == 'False' or true_false_statement == 'F' or true_false_statement == 'f':
                number = number - (ord(keyword[keyword_index])) - ord('a')
            keyword_index += 1
            keyword_index = keyword_index % len(keyword)

            if number >= len(alphabet):
                number = number - len(alphabet)
            elif number < 0:
                number = number + len(alphabet)


            translated_message = translated_message + alphabet[number]

        else:
            translated_message = translated_message + character

    return (translated_message)



def main():
    message = input("Enter string you want to encrypt/decrypt: ")
    keyword = input('Keyword for encryption: ')
    true_false_statement = ''
    translated_message = fancy_caesar(message, keyword, true_false_statement)
    print(translated_message)


main()
```

I tried adding `self` to the `cleanup()` function which did not work at all since I was not given anything but blank in the ouput.

```
def fancy_caesar(message, keyword, true_false_statement):
    message = cleanup(message)
    keyword = cleanup(keyword)
    count = 0
    while count == 0:
```

I tried calling the `cleanup()` within the `main()` function and I got the same result.

This could be due to the fact that `my_string` isn't called in `def string()`

Which I ended up excluding it out of the `cleanup()` function in order for me to use the function for the `fancy_caesar`. Could I get any tips to solve these issues?

The output should result in the input string being all capatalized with no spaces or special characters which is done by the `cleanup` function.

Comment: So your problem is the function isn't returning anything? Keep in mind that you can't set global variables in a function, nor can you set the values of variables passed in and access them in the outside of the function.

Comment: `self` is conventionally used as the argument to methods in classes. Don't use it as an ordinary variable, it's confusing.

Comment: You never use `my_string` anywhere, why do you need to clean it up?

Comment: I need to clean up the message and keyword inputs that come from the user. I am not sure whether it would be best to call the `cleanup` function inside the `main` function or inside the `fancy_caesar` function. Either way I am having trouble getting the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cleanup()` should take the string to be cleaned as a parameter.

```
def cleanup(my_string):
    res = ''
    _char = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    lower_char = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    all_char = _char + lower_char
    for ch in my_string:
        if ch in all_char:
            res += ch
    return (res.upper())
```

Then you use it like this:

```
some_string = cleanup(some_string)
```

Comment: what if I want to clean-up the message and keyword inputs first rather than cleaning up the translated message?

Comment: You can do it with any string, that's just an example.

Comment: I tried doing `cleanup(keyword)` and `cleanup(message)` and I got blank outputs

Comment: Try `print(cleanup(keyword))`

Comment: do you recommend doing it in the `def main` function or in the `def fancy_caesar`?

Comment: Do it wherever it makes the most sense.

Comment: whenever I try to do special characters or type it in uppercase for the `keyword` function, it says `index out of range` or I just get the the message input back.

Comment: I just tested `cleanup("abc 12 FOARbar")` and the result was `ABCFOARBAR`

Comment: I haven't looked at the rest of your script, you probably have other problems unrelated to the `cleanup()` function.

Comment: I've tried adding the `cleanup()` function in other locations where `keyword` is called but no luck. I'm stuck..

Comment: Doing `keyword = cleanup(keyword)` should be all you need. `keyword_index = keyword_index % len(keyword)` prevents the index from getting out of range.

Comment: If you can't solve it, post another question with the updated code. And leave out irrelevant functions like `string`, `swap` and `inputs`.